# Arduino beginners kit example not working

Tags: arduino-uno

I bought a beginners kit and can get all but one of the examples to work. I have tried different board layouts and varied the code with no success. When I first run the code the LED is off. When I ground pin 9 the LED comes on and stays on. Grounding pin 8 does not turn off the LED once it is lit.

```
int ledPin = 5;
int buttonApin = 9;
int buttonBpin = 8;

byte leds = 0;

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonApin, INPUT_PULLUP);  
  pinMode(buttonBpin, INPUT_PULLUP);  
}

void loop() 
{
  if (digitalRead(buttonApin) == LOW)
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  }
  if (digitalRead(buttonBpin) == LOW)
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
}
```

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: Code should read:

Comment: Does pin 9 stay grounded after the LED turns on? If you ground both pins with that code you will have the LED at about half intensity, since you are turning it off and on very fast

Comment: Pin 9 is only grounded momentarily but the LED stays on afterwards. After I press the button and release I assume both 8 and 9 are floating, but neither are grounded until I press a button again.

Comment: I have tested this with your wiring and your code and it works like a charm. I can turn off the LED with the button at pin 8. You must have done something different, than you stated in your question

Comment: Thanks Chris. I will have another go. I have tried a few times now with no success and different configurations.

Comment: Maybe you can post a good photo of your actual circuit. And some breadboards have the outer rails divided in two parts. If that is the case, button 8 would not be connected to ground. Please check that.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Works now. May have been a bad connection.

Comment: A multimeter can be useful in troubleshooting hardware setups. You could use it to check that pin 8 is actually being shorted to ground when the button is pressed, for example. (Set the meter to continuity mode, attach one lead to a spare ground on the Arduino, and the other to the pin 8 section of your breadboard. The meter should beep when you press the button. If not, start working backwards until you figure out where you have an open circuit.

Comment: touch the yellow button to ground instead of pressing the button

Comment: If you have conected it exactly like in the image, maybe you've got breadboard with power rails separated in the middle (I've got plenty of them and they all have this "feature"). However it's also displayed by colored lines next to it. If there is a space in the middle, it's not connected

Answer (score 0):

This kind of button has 4 pins. These pins are internally connected in pairs. It's easy to make a mistake when wiring. Please post the real picture of your wiring. Or you can refer to read more about button pin [in this post](https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-button#content_about_button)